# Excel behaving improperly for values with decimal places exported from Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, csv

I am using `angular-ui-grid` and its export to csv functionality. In `csv` file data is coming properly. I am using below filter function on numerical data.

```
HelperServices.filter('customCurrencyFormat',function($filter){
    return function(val, cond , decimalPlaces){

        if(typeof decimalPlaces =='undefined' || decimalPlaces ==null ){
            decimalPlaces = 2;
        }

        if(val == "0" && cond == "showZero"){
            return ($filter('currency')(val, "", decimalPlaces));
        }else if(val == 0 && cond == "hideZero"){
            return null;
        }else{
            if(val < 0){
                console.log(($filter('currency')(val, "", decimalPlaces)).replace("(", "-").replace(")", ""));
                return ($filter('currency')(val, "", decimalPlaces)).replace("(", "-").replace(")", "");
            }else{
                return ($filter('currency')(val, "", decimalPlaces));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here `console.log` statement print below output which is correct:

[image: values on console]

And when I open exported `csv` in excel, it displays like this:

[image: values in excel]

The value "-310.00" is displaying as "-310" in excel (without trailing zeros) and even value "-10,978.00" has trailing zeros but it comes exactly as same as it is printed on console.

**One thing I noticed is that if "," comes to the value it is printed correctly in excel. But with `angualrjs` currency filter "," does not come for 3 digit values.**

**Why excel is removing trailing zeros for some values and not removing for some other values ?**

Comment: I also have same issue. We decided to remove .00 and .0 .

Answer (score 0):

Excel tries to guess the most appropriate number format for you. If you enter `1.0` in Excel manually, it will be displayed as `1` (because Excel's catch-all "Standard" format is being used). If you enter `1,000.0`, it will be displayed as `1,000.00` (because Excel switches to "Number" formatting which is necessary to keep the thousands separators visible. It also defaults to two decimal places).

In both cases, the numbers are stored correctly - just assign the "Number" type to the entire column.

Comment: type number is already applied to the grid column in angularjs code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this, but I am sure that this information is lost when saving a `csv` file. They are simple text files that can't conserve metadata such as datatypes.

Comment: Ok I got your point that information is lost when saving to csv. Then why would some values are coming with filter applied to it ?

Comment: When reading a text file such as `csv`, Excel will try to guess the cell type for each value, just as if you had entered it manually. You *can*  tell the import filter whether to treat values in a certain column as standard values, texts, or dates (using the "Add from text" button of the "Data" ribbon), but unfortunately you can't specify a number format.